# How to create an NSDate date object? 

Tags: objective-c

How can I create an `NSDate` from the day, month and year? There don't seem to be any methods to do this and they have removed the class method `dateWithString` (why would they do that?!).

Comment: dateWithString: is gone because in the past it was defined to apply heuristics to guess what date a string meant to describe. Such guessing wasn't always particularly accurate, and definitely wasn't a good way to advocate that people write their applications. Answers below are correct — philosophically you need to know which calendar you're using for a date to be unambiguous, so Cocoa classes are organised around that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could write a category for this. I did that, this is how the code looks:

```
//  NSDateCategory.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDate (MBDateCat) 

+ (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day;

@end



//  NSDateCategory.m

#import "NSDateCategory.h"

@implementation NSDate (MBDateCat)

+ (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [components setYear:year];
    [components setMonth:month];
    [components setDay:day];
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}

@end
```

Use it like this: `NSDate *aDate = [NSDate dateWithYear:2010 month:5 day:12];`

Comment: It just blows my mind the amount of code one will need to write just to create a date in objective C!

Comment: The defence argument would be that an NSDate uniquely identifies a moment in the Earth's history. There are many ways to write a date (in common use today, at least the Gregorian, Hebrew and Islamic calendars), so that's a separate logical thing. In Cocoa you use an NSCalendar object to disambiguate that. And the cost is that what you might want to be one line of code ends up being six, which — as in fluchtpunkt's answer — is easy enough to squirrel off into library code.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:6];
[comps setMonth:5];
[comps setYear:2004];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];
```

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different answer to those already posted; if you have a fixed string format you'd like to use to create dates then you can use something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]; 
    // see QA1480; NSDateFormatter otherwise reserves the right slightly to
    // modify any date string passed to it, according to user settings, per
    // it's other use, for UI work

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy"; 
    // or whatever you want; per the unicode standards

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringContainingDate];
```