# Notify in specific date and time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I need help from you: I have to set the code notify in specific date and time. Please help me to fix my code.

```
UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
n1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 6];
n1.alertBody = @"one";
UILocalNotification* n2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
n2.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 15];
n2.alertBody = @"two";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n2];
```

Comment: What's the issue? What doesn't work? Both code?

Comment: What does not work (i.e. what is your specific problem)?

Comment: the notification should work on specific date

Comment: You mean you need alternate methods to create `NSDate` other than `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:`?

Comment: but it has to work with dateWithTimeInterval

Comment: Well, that's note related to Notification. You should use NSDateComponents, look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154082/how-to-create-an-nsdate-date-object

Comment: when i run the my 1st (@"ONE") notification has to run in specific time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just don't know how to create an `NSDate` to a specific time. Use [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) to convert strings to dates.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:@"2014-04-05 23:30"];

UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
n1.fireDate = myDate;
```

Comment: please some one help me to fix when i run the my 1st (@"ONE") notification has to run in specific time